# How to change the grid point coordinates at which the flow field velocity will be recorded using the FlorisInterface?

Tags: floris

I would like to change the grid point coordinates at which I calculate the wake so I can properly compare it to CFD simulations.

Currently, I am using the FLORIS framework with `FlorisInterface`.
It seems that I could either choose to define the points in `calculate_wake(points=...)` or by defining the resolution (`with_resolution=Vec3`) and x,y,z-bounds (`bounds_to_set=...`) when reinitializing the flow field with `reinitialize_flow_field(...)`.

There are problems I come across:

1. when using `FlorisInterface` it seems that it cannot find the parameter `bounds_to_set` in `reinitialize_flow_field(...)`, however it is present in `simulation.flow_field`.
2. I have trouble figuring out how `points=...` needs to be formatted in `calculate_wake(points=...)`; the documentation says it is an array containing x-, y-, and z-coordinates, but I am not sure how the array should be shaped.

What is generally the most appropriate way to define user-specified grid points in the set-up?

Answer (score 0):

have you looked at the example:

examples/flow_interaction/get_points_from_flow.py

This shows how to select arbitrary points from 1D x,y,z arrays:

```
# Define a set points running through one row
x_points = np.arange(-100, 1000, 1)
y_points = np.zeros_like(x_points)
z_points = np.ones_like(x_points) * 100

# Get the values
flow_points = fi.get_set_of_points(x_points, y_points, z_points)

print(flow_points)
```